# Word or phrase stronger than "most likely"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Imagine this context:

> [After we replaced the monitor](https://superuser.com/a/1024186/498587), everything was fixed. Therefor the monitor was **most likely** the source of the problem.

I feel like given the right context, "most likely" doesn't sound *strong* enough, if that's the right word to use.

If I am 100% confident, I will say:

> He **is** wrong.

If I am 70-90% confident:

> He is **most likely** wrong.

But if I am 99% sure, what is a word or phrase that can get that message across?

Comment: He is 99% wrong.

Comment: @Rathony Sounds juvenile.

Comment: What I tried to mean was your question could generate primarily-opinion based answers. To some people most likely could mean 60% and to some 95%. What is the difference between 99% and 100%? Does "He is 100% wrong" sound juvenile to you, too?

Comment: @Rathony It can. So can all the related questions on the sidebar that ask for "a word stronger than ..". And on that note, it's my opinion that using the whole % thing sounds juvenile :P

Answer (score 2):

almost certainly

> Therefore, the monitor was **almost certainly** the source of the problem.

a high propensity to be

> Therefore, there is a **high propensity** the monitor is the source of the
>   problem.

was in all likelihood

> Therefore, the monitor is **in all likelihood** the source of the problem.

most probably was

> Therefore, the monitor was **most probably** the source of the problem.

in all probability was

> Therefore, the monitor was **in all probability** the source of the
>   problem.

there was every chance that

> Therefore, there was **every chance** the monitor was the source of the
>   problem.

snowball's chance in hell

> Therefore, there was only a **snowball's chance in hell** the monitor was
>   not the source of the problem.

Comment: If brevity mattered, I would choose "almost certainly" even though it doesn't sound that much better than "most likely". Otherwise, I think "in all probability was" takes the cake because it implies that the probability of other cases was considered.

Comment: In statistics, "propensity" is often used.  For example, you often see statistics that describe the probability of voters, particularly by demographic, to turn out at the poles described as "propensity."  "Due to talked about changes in Medicare, poling numbers indicate senior citizens have a high propensity to show up and vote this November."

Answer (score 2):

To me *all but certain* and *virtually certain* feel stronger than *most likely*:

> It is ***all but certain*** that the monitor was the source of the problem.
>
> It is ***virtually certain*** that the monitor was the source of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, yeah I like "all but certain".

Comment: @Insane Glad to be of assistance. Dictionaries define *all but* as *almost*, but it feels stronger to me.